# Jetpack Compose app crashes continuously with ViewModel

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm following Google Android Developer codelabs on ViewModel and State. There's a codelab to port an app called Dessert Clicker to ViewModel.

My attempt can be found here:

https://github.com/alghe-global/Kotlin/tree/viewmodel/AndroidBasicsCourse%2FDessertClicker

Unfortunately, the app crashes on startup.

`onCreate()` is not logged (Logcat is empty), and, placing a breakpoint on `super.onCreate(...)` in MainActivity won't trigger it leading me to suspect there's a fundamental problem in the way the APK is set-up.

The codelab does provide a solution, however I'm trying to learn how to debug and deal with these kind of issues so if they arise in the future I know what to do.

Any hints are appreciated.

---

### Solution

Looking at Logcat, I realized that the device selected was wrong (my phone was selected instead of the AVD I was using to debug).

Once the correct device was set, I could see the stacktrace in the log:

```
2024-01-11 11:11:11.119 12385-12385 AndroidRuntime          com.example.dessertclicker           E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.dessertclicker, PID: 12385
                                                                                                    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
                                                                                                        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:234)
                                                                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1439)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.res.PainterResources_androidKt.painterResource(PainterResources.android.kt:61)
                                                                                                        at com.example.dessertclicker.MainActivityKt.DessertClickerScreen(MainActivity.kt:230)
...
```

This pointed to a resource I was using in the wrong way (UiState instead of ViewModel).

This was resolved with:

```
diff --git a/AndroidBasicsCourse/DessertClicker/app/src/main/java/com/example/dessertclicker/MainActivity.kt b/AndroidBasicsCourse/DessertClicker/app/src/main/java/com/example/dessertclicker/MainActivity.kt
index 6dffdf0..a9599ee 100644
--- a/AndroidBasicsCourse/DessertClicker/app/src/main/java/com/example/dessertclicker/MainActivity.kt
+++ b/AndroidBasicsCourse/DessertClicker/app/src/main/java/com/example/dessertclicker/MainActivity.kt
@@ -164,7 +164,7 @@ private fun DessertClickerApp(
         DessertClickerScreen(
             revenue = dessertClickerUiState.revenue,
             dessertsSold = dessertClickerUiState.dessertsSold,
-            dessertImageId = dessertClickerUiState.currentDessertImageId,
+            dessertImageId = dessertClickerViewModel.currentDessertImageId,
             onDessertClicked = {
                 dessertClickerViewModel.updateRevenue()
                 dessertClickerViewModel.updateDessertsSold()
```

Thanks to @a_local_nobody for his/her/their help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: considering your request of `I'm trying to learn how to debug` then there's no better post than that

Comment: Thanks. I realized that I was looking at the wrong device in logcat.

Comment: great, glad it helped. also nice to see that you wanted to understand how to solve the problem yourself, which is quite rare these days, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

Looking at Logcat, I realized that the device selected was wrong (my phone was selected instead of the AVD I was using to debug).

Once the correct device was set, I could see the stacktrace in the log:

```
2024-01-11 11:11:11.119 12385-12385 AndroidRuntime          com.example.dessertclicker           E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.dessertclicker, PID: 12385
                                                                                                    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
                                                                                                        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:234)
                                                                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1439)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.res.PainterResources_androidKt.painterResource(PainterResources.android.kt:61)
                                                                                                        at com.example.dessertclicker.MainActivityKt.DessertClickerScreen(MainActivity.kt:230)
...
```

This pointed to a resource I was using in the wrong way (UiState instead of ViewModel).

This was resolved with:

```
diff --git a/AndroidBasicsCourse/DessertClicker/app/src/main/java/com/example/dessertclicker/MainActivity.kt b/AndroidBasicsCourse/DessertClicker/app/src/main/java/com/example/dessertclicker/MainActivity.kt
index 6dffdf0..a9599ee 100644
--- a/AndroidBasicsCourse/DessertClicker/app/src/main/java/com/example/dessertclicker/MainActivity.kt
+++ b/AndroidBasicsCourse/DessertClicker/app/src/main/java/com/example/dessertclicker/MainActivity.kt
@@ -164,7 +164,7 @@ private fun DessertClickerApp(
         DessertClickerScreen(
             revenue = dessertClickerUiState.revenue,
             dessertsSold = dessertClickerUiState.dessertsSold,
-            dessertImageId = dessertClickerUiState.currentDessertImageId,
+            dessertImageId = dessertClickerViewModel.currentDessertImageId,
             onDessertClicked = {
                 dessertClickerViewModel.updateRevenue()
                 dessertClickerViewModel.updateDessertsSold()
```

Thanks to @a_local_nobody for his/her/their help!